# IntelliJ IDEA doesn't recognise angular 4 html tags

Tags: javascript, html, angular, intellij-idea

The plugin "AngularJS" is, as far as I know, for Angular < 2 and doesn't support Angular 4.

I have an entire project which builds with `ng build` and so on, however IDEA doesn't support the HTML tags such as "fxLayout"

It produces the message: "Attribute fxLayout is not allowed here"

How do I configure IntelliJ IDEA to allow Angular4 html tags?

Comment: Do you have angularJS plugin installed and enabled?

Comment: Yes, I have installed the AngularJS plugin for the project and enabled it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first AngularJS plugin should be installed via **Settings | Plugins | Install JetBrains plugin.**

Then it should work automatically as long as you have angular.js in your web module.

**AngularJS plugin requires JavaScript support that is not available in Community version**

Comment: I have the plugin and IDEA ultimate edition. It does not work out of the box with those.

Comment: Could the issue be that the project consists of two modules, one of which is an Angular project? And that the Angularjs plugin is configured to the project root rather than the module?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove .idea folder and reopen the project